# How to use CDF in excel - can someone also explain CDF in a little laymen terms?

Tags: excel, find, cdf

```
   Column A         Column B
   74.220.195.50    0
   203.190.242.69   0
   72.21.202.164    2311.3064862163
   80.239.175.42    1239.6495360036
   61.200.220.183   0
   81.92.239.90     195.4399850652
   95.100.159.8     9.49352979660034E-005
   211.125.95.155   10031.6661327213
   165.72.192.114   0
   207.210.105.72   0
   65.55.239.161    9.801753891
   221.231.132.97   0
   209.85.148.95    9644.360436176
```

How can I find the CDF from the data that I have above.
I want Column B in the X axis and the Y axis is Column A (Target IP addresses)

Comment: which CDF? http://www.google.com/search?q=cdf

Comment: Cumulative distribution function

Comment: i need to find the distribution

Answer (score 0):

If you don't already have the data analysis toolpack installed, you can add it by going to Tools > Add-ins.

After you confirm that it has been installed please go to page 175 of this document:

http://www.dssbooks.com/excel/Files/Look%20Inside/Spreadsheet--DSS-Chapter-07.pdf